# How to listen on my public IP address port using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want my Nodejs app to be accessed using my public IP address rather than the localhost. Right now for hosting my application on localhost I am doing:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT||9000,()=>{
    console.log('Server is running on 9000!')
})
```

I wanted to setup Nodejs to Nodejs communication. I got help from stackoverflow and 
used the npm `request` package to send a post request from one of my nodejs server running on port 3000 to the one running on port 9000

```
const request = require("request");

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: { id: 1 },
    json: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    // console.log(body);
    // Process the body and return the response.
    // return res.send(body);
});
```

I however want to use a public IP address because I want to host one of my server on Heroku. I will need the public IP address to create a communication

Comment: What have you tried till now with respect to deploying your application? Do you have a server setup and access to it? Do you want to dockerize the application?

Answer (score 1):

**How to make your node.js listening on you public IP**  :

Actually your nodejs server listen on `port 9000`, wich mean any communication on this port will be listen. THe only thing you need is to **open this port** to allow request from "outside".

For `heroku`, I don't think you can do this. But, according to the documentation, **port 80 and 443 are already open**, so if you change your port to one of these it would work!

*Bonus :*

**How to open a port (on Linux)**

You can use ufw, an easy and famous firewall manager.

```
sudo ufw allow 9000
```

This command will open your port 9000 and allow external request to resquest your nodejs server

I recommend you to read the doc of [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) before, and see this good [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04)